# Unix Line count command

Tags: unix

I have a file as below -

---

Printed sometext
Requested something else1
Requested something else2
Requested something else3
Printed sometext
Requested something else4
Requested something else5
Printed sometext
Requested something else6
Requested something else7
Requested something else8
Requested something else9

---

I need the below output -

```
Printed sometext
3
Printed sometext
2
Printed sometext
4
```

Could anyone let me know how can we achieve this?

Comment: take a look at `awk` (example here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265210/count-all-lines-between-a-delimiter)

Comment: I *assume* you are asking how to count the lines between a fixed string, printing each line that exactly matches that fixed string, suppressing all other output and replacing it with the count of the suppressed lines.  But that is not at all clear from the question.  Although giving an example of your desired output is desirable and often necessary, it is not a substitute for actually explaining what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/line/{ print NR; exit }' input-file
```

Above command gives the line numbers of occurances of the string line in input-file.
Now you can get the line numbers containing the separator text and subtracting them suitably gives you number of lines

edit: Works only if the separator text is not a part of any other line other than the separating lines

Answer (score 1):

use `nl {filename}` . first use `cat` and `pipe` through [nl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nl_(Unix)). `nl` also takes file as input.

For e.g. `cat pgadmin.log | nl` will display something like this.

```
   ...
   ...
   120  ERROR  : 11:46:32 AM: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
   121  LINE 10: created_at as "Lead Creation Date",
   ...
   ...
```

For detailed information see `man nl` on Unix platform.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your input is in file 1.txt and you need to count all lines except specific one (as in your sample), then you can use:

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{if ($0 == "Printed sometext") { if (count>0) print count; print $0; count = 0; } else { count++;} } END { if (count>0) print count;}'
```

It produces output as you need for your test data.

Comment: This is not quite idiomatic awk.  More typical would be `awk '/^Printed sometext$/{if(l)print l; print; l=0; next}{l++} END{print l}' input`  (avoid the UUOC and use a pattern rather than an if statement in an action).

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell! I just too used to UUOC unfortunately